# How do I return a json file from s3 to a specific url, but only that url

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-router, amazon-cloudfront

I have a special URL that has been set somewhere else and **CANNOT be changed.**

mydomain.com/discountCards

I need to return a JSON, from my s3 bucket whenever a server sends a fetch call to `mydomain.com/discountCards`

The issue is:

I'm using a react app on mydomain.com with React-Router. So going to mydomain.com/discountCards displays a white react page (since nothing is at that url)

I'm trying to set up Cloudfront to directly link to the s3 JSON file which works - but the issue is:

it only works for mydomain.com/discountCards.json not mydomain.com/discountCards

So.... right now my s3 bucket has a file called discountCards.json - but I need that to be discountCard without the ".json".

Or something else?

How do I return this .json from my s3, as a specific domain, using AWS s3, cloudfront, and route 53?

Like I said, I got it all set up with cloudfront pointing to my s3 file, but it requires I include the file extension in the URL (which I cannot do, the url is already locked in stone at mydomain.com/discountCards not discountCards.json)

This is so that other websites and apps can fetch that URL and get a json returned. Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Just wondering whether you could active Static Website Hosting on the S3 bucket with CloudFront using it as an Origin. Then, when CloudFront goes to the bucket, the default (index) page could be the .json file?

Comment: Why don't you name your file `discountCards` (without extension) in S3 with the right content type (`application/json`) it should work

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm currently using that bucket's index as my react app. So its being used. I've used Cloudfront and set my json as the origin and like I said, it works with the exact name of the file.

Comment: Will try renaming it as @jogold suggests. Thank you will let you know

Comment: @jogold Did not work. Still get the react page. Unless there is a way to make mydomain.com/discountCards a CNAME record, I don't see how it will work. React is displaying on that address...

Comment: Are you okay with a redirection to json file when accessing discountCards ? If so:
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
       <KeyPrefixEquals>discountCards</KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <ReplaceKeyWith>folderdeleted.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
    </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
  </RoutingRules>

Comment: The only other option when S3 website endpoint does what you want is when you set the index page as .json file

Comment: Can you share your CloudFront configuration? Origins and cache behaviors?

Comment: @jogold https://imgur.com/xVWtoi1 I'm pointing my cloudfront to my s3 bucket, in that bucket my react app index.html is the static hosted file that is displayed. I have react router handling routes, so /discountcards is loaded in react. 

In cloudfront, I have added a direct origin to my .json file in my s3 bucket. That cloudfront link displays it properly if I go to the cloudfront link. 

If i go to mydomain.com/discountcards.json it works. But mydomain.com/discountcards is my react page and not my json.

Cannot do a redirect either. Needs to be fetchable from a server or curl fetch

Comment: Do you have custom error pages configured? Also service worker in the frontend? You should be able to do it with only one origin

Comment: wondering if this can be done using lambda@edge origin request.

Comment: @jogold Can you please explain how to do it? I don't have custom error pages, and react create app comes with a service worker. 

What should I do to get a .json returned?

Comment: Can you share the url to your website?

Comment: @jogold rather not publically say it - do you have a way for me to provide it to you privately?

Comment: Not really, isn't your website public? The thing I need to understand is why `/discountcards` is routed to react.

Comment: >  Cannot do a redirect either. Needs to be fetchable from a server or curl fetch
---
You can add the `-L` flag to a curl fetch to get it to follow redirects. I'm sure there's analogous functionality for fetching from a server

Answer (score 7):

> So.... right now my s3 bucket has a file called discountCards.json -
>   but I need that to be discountCard without the ".json"

Save your file discountCard.json as discountCard without .json extension. See the image below

[image]

Then on properties under metadata add `content-type` to `application/json` see image below

[image]

Accessing the bucket is now possible through this url https://s3.amazonaws.com/stackkkover/discountCards

This answer was inspired by this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/27046083/3521330

I hope this answer will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Actually - this was easier than the first one. It worked! Thank you. I

Answer (score 1):

I have created a lambda function, which in conjunction with CloudFront will help you achieve what you are looking for without any redirects.

Create a S3 bucket, I set it up as Static hosting with two files `index.html` and `discountCards.json`.
[Static site Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VUnB.png)

In CloudFront:-

[Cloudfront settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8RxC.png)  Create a CF with the S3 bucket static website as the origin. Do not use the S3 bucket from the dropdown. You have used an incorrect origin i.e a JSON file. Only use a bucket as an origin and folder as an origin path.

Next, create a lambda function with the following code: 
[Lambda Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbf3b.png)

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;
    const origin = request.origin;
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;

    console.log("The initial origin is " + JSON.stringify(origin)); //Shows the original origin 
    console.log("The Initial request is " + JSON.stringify(request)); //Shows the original origin request  
    const originDomain = origin.custom.domainName;

    // Checks the request uri for the `/discountCards` and replaces it with `/discountCards.json 
    if (request.uri == "/discountCards") {
        request.uri = "/discountCards.json";
    }

    console.log("The final origin is " + JSON.stringify(origin)); //Shows the final origin
    console.log("The final request is " + JSON.stringify(request)); //Shows the final request
    callback(null, request); };
```

The lambda function will modify the request.uri to the file you want to serve and since it is being served by CloudFront, the URL in the browser will remain the same.

Save the lambda function and publish it with a version number/tag.

Go to the CloudFront distribution > Behaviors(Choose the default behaviour) > Edit. Go to the bottom of the page to lambda function associations, choose "Origin request" and paste the lambda function ARN (available from the lambda function page, upper right corner) and save and invalidate the cache. 
[It should Look like this. at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNquT.png)

[The bucket site index.html!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRBoY.png)

[The bucket with contents of discountCards.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mXqU.png)

#### Actual site with Route53 + Cloudfront + Lambda

[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsgml.png) 
Voila! The page will serve the JSON file on the desired path!! Without any redirection. remember to **Invalidate Cache**