# Serving a JSON file from an AWS Amplify React Project

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have an AWS Amplify React project associated with our domain, which leads to all files and contents being sourced by the underlying react router.

In order to support backend API communications with Microsoft APIs, we need to host a specific JSON file at a particular location within our domain, such as mydomain.com/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json.

I am unsure how to do this. My first question is whether this is best accomplished via static routes within the react router or, instead, configuring Cloud Front and Route 53 to serve up the JSON file for this exact URL.

I have been trying the second approach and have created a distribution in Cloud Front for a specific S3 bucket storing the JSON file.  I have named the S3 bucket "mydomain" with a subfolder ".well-known" and a contained JSON filed entitled "microsoft-identity-association.json".  My problem is that I do not know how to configure Route 53 to route to this distribution as my root domain (mydomain.com) is associated with my Amplify project and is handled by the react router.  I'm not sure if I can somehow configure a specific route or alias to serve up the exact JSON file.

I have reviewed this post ([How do I return a json file from s3 to a specific url, but only that url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56087853/how-do-i-return-a-json-file-from-s3-to-a-specific-url-but-only-that-url)) but it seems to be addressing a slightly different problem.

Any and all guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Addressed this issue by splitting my site.  I used a static S3-hosted site for public pages (including the JSON file) and redirected the React app to a subdomain.