# Website hosted on AWS - removing .html from the end of the url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm a newb when it comes to AWS cloud computing, but any feedback would be appreciated. I'm looking to remove the .html from urls of my website hosted on AWS.

I have all of the front-end code in an S3 bucket, which I have hosted with an EC2 instance and route 53. The code is not the problem, as I have a .htaccess file with the following code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

That got everything to work just fine on my local server, but the .html still appears on the URL.

[S3 static pages without .html extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463679/s3-static-pages-without-html-extension)

I stumbled across this article, and I tried every suggestion. Nothing worked.

I then came across this code to apply in lambda:

https://github.com/CloudUnder/lambda-edge-nice-urls/blob/master/lambdaRewrite.js

I pasted that code in there, got everything set with Lambda and Cloudfront. Created a role with the following permissions:

```
Allow: s3:PutObject
Allow: s3:GetObject
Allow: s3:GetBucketWebsite
Allow: s3:PutBucketWebsite
Allow: s3:CreateBucket
Allow: s3:DeleteObject
Allow: s3:DeleteBucket
```

I also set the origin for the S3 bucket in Cloudfront as well.

Where in the process do you think I could have course corrected or gotten this thing to work?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and I'd like to share the solution:

You have to set the metadata of the file Content-type to text/html AND rename the file removing the .html of the end.

That way you will be able to reach every page without the file extension.