# Custom url of static website hosted on aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a static website hosted on aws s3 bucket. I want to set custom URL for every page in my website. like www.site.com/folder/subfolder/file.html to www.site.com/filename. What is the simplest way to do this.

Comment: The only way this is possible in S3 is with redirects.  If a user types `http://example.com/lolcats` S3 can be configured to redirect the browser to another path in the bucket, such as `http://example.com/pictures/funny/cats.html`, but with this, the browser's address bar will change to the "real" (long) address. Is that something that would work for you?

Comment: You could do that with some code in .htaccess file but afaik it's not supported in s3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Pages on a Static Website AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226430/multiple-pages-on-a-static-website-aws-s3)

Answer (score -1):

Follow below steps to achieve this.

1) buy your domain, `example.com`

2) go to the Amazon S3 console and create a bucket named `example.com`

3) add your `index.html` file to it and provide read permissions

4) enable static website hosting for the bucket, using `example.com` in the field

5) go to the R53 routing part of the console and add a `Type A` record set (IPV4)

6) Select Yes for Alias and choose the endpoint from the drop down, it will be something like

```
example.com..s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

7) Hit 'Create'

8) Go back to Hosted Zones and click the `example.com` zone, on the right you will see 4 namespaces that look something like this:

```
ns-XXXX.awsdns-54.org
ns-XXX.awsdns-15.com
ns-XXXX.awsdns-45.co.uk
ns-XXX.awsdns-27.net
```

9) Copy these namespaces to a notepad or something

10) The Amazon side is now configured, we just need to do the domain side, so in my case I went to `iwantmyname.com`

11) Go to edit namespaces, and change them to the ones you copied from step 8

12) We're done! Just be patient as it does take some time to configure all of this. In my case it took about 15 minutes. You can ping the website or use nslookup to check up on the progress through your console:

```
ping example.com
nslookup example.com
```

pinging is inferior to nslookup with S3 since Amazon blocks them

Comment: No sorry but I don't want this my website is already hosted on s3 bucket and assessable with domain name also. I just want custom URL for every single page like I mention above.

Comment: This does not address the OP desire to redirect requests for `/filename` to `/folder/subfolder/file.html`.